# <buildfiles> does not support the nested build element "references"

Tags: .net, nant

I'm receiving this below error for the below nant script can somebody help :(

Error is :  ***does not support the nested build element "references".***

Please find the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="NAnt Examples" default="build">
    <target name="*">
        <nant target="${target::get-current-target()}">
            <buildfiles>
                <include name="**/*.build" />
                <references>
                <include name="C:/Program Files/NAnt/examples/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll" />
                </references>
                <!-- avoid recursive execution of current build file -->
                <exclude name="${project::get-buildfile-path()}" />

                <exclude name="ScriptTask/script-sample.build" />
                <exclude name="Solution/**/*.build"/>
            </buildfiles>
        </nant>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You receive this error because the `<buildfiles>` element, which is a usual `<fileset>` doesn't support the `<references>` to be its child element. See the description of the [`<nant>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/nant.html) task for more details.

Comment: Do i have to use <buildfiles> Or <fileset>

Comment: You have to use `<buildfiles>` inside the `<nant>`, because it's defined by the `<nant>` task syntax, but the type of the `<buildfiles>` element is `fileset`, thus you should and have to use any of the options for the fileset contents: http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/types/fileset.html. Treat it as if it's usual `<fileset>`, but named differently.

Comment: I will use <buildfiles> , but How can i mention references in the nant script ?

Comment: I wonder why you need the references? The contents of the `<buildfiles>` is supposed to be just a set of files, after NAnt calculates all include/exclude rules...